# Inequalities involving elementary functions

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, elementary-functions

Let $k\gt0$ and consider the real sequence $(u_n)_{n\geqslant1}$. Moreover, let
\begin{equation}
T_k u_n :=\begin{cases}
u_n &\hbox{ if } \vert u_n\vert\leqslant k\\[5pt]
k\frac{u_n}{\vert u_n\vert} &\hbox{ if } \vert u_n\vert > k
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and define $v_{k, n}:= T_k u_n -u$.

How could I prove that
$$ \vert\varphi(v_{k, n})\vert\leqslant\varphi(2k) \quad \mbox{ and }\quad 0 <\varphi^{\prime}(v_{k,n})\leqslant\varphi^{\prime}(2k),$$
where $\varphi(t)$ denotes the real map $\phi(t) = t e^{\eta t^2}$, with $\eta\gt 0$?

May I ask for help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is $u$? and do you mean $v_{k,n} = T_k(u_n - u)$ or $(T_ku_n) - u$?

Comment: I mean $v_{k,n} = T_k u_n - u$ and $u$ is such that $u_n\longrightarrow u$ a.e. I’m sorry if I was not so clear.